# Laravel hasManyThrough return only related model's data

Tags: mysql, laravel, has-many-through

I have the following models

```
Member
    -id
    -full_name
    -others...

AllowanceBill
    -id
    -others...

Payment
    -allowance_bill_id
    -member_id
    -total_amount
    -payable_amount
```

and I'm using this relationship on the AllowanceBill model

```
public function members(){
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        Member::class,
        Payment::class,
        'allowance_bill_id',
        'id',
        'id',
        'member_id'
    );
}
```

I want to display a table of a specific bill, let's say Bill#2 with this format

Member ID, Full Name, Total Amount, Payable Amount

but using this in show() callback of AllowanceBillController

```
$allowanceBill->members()->get();
```

returns all the payments, not just the payments specific to bill#2

Any idea why it's not working?

Comment: Shouldn't Allowance Bill have member_id field?

Comment: No, AllowanceBill is for the Payments, and payments are related to members.